# PIG Script error, while trying to store in AVRO format: Datum 2 is not in union ["null","string"]

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig, avro, piggybak

I'm trying to store data to AVRO format, but can not realize why I'm getting error. Datum 2 is not in union ["null","string"] what does it mean?

> Parse xml:

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar
REGISTER /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/lib/avro.jar
REGISTER /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar
REGISTER /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath()
DEFINE XMLLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('data')
A = LOAD 'input' using XMLLoader as (x:chararray); 
R = RANK A; 
B = FOREACH R GENERATE 
        $0 as (id:chararray),
        ToString(CurrentTime(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS') as (CreatedTS:chararray),
        CONCAT((chararray)XPath(x, 'data/key'), '_', ToString(CurrentTime(), 'yyMMddHmm'),'_',(chararray)$0) as (FileName:chararray), 
        XPath(x, 'data/title') as (title:chararray), 
        XPath(x, 'data/city') as (city:chararray),
        XPath(x, 'data/country') as (country:chararray),
        XPath(x, 'data/text') as (text:chararray),
        XPath(x, 'data/empty_text') as (empty_text:chararray); 
C = DISTINCT B; 
DUMP C;
```

> DUMP C:

```
(2,2017-06-12 14:21:35.937000,f385a4_1706121421_2,Data text for two,תל אביב -יפו,IL,תל אביב -יפו, מחוז תל אביב,)
(3,2017-06-12 14:21:35.937000,657e21_1706121421_3,Data text three,תל אביב -יפו,IL,תל אביב -יפו,)
(4,2017-06-12 14:21:35.937000,5700da_1706121421_4,Data text four,Dublin,IE,Text data for example,)
(1,2017-06-12 14:21:35.937000,22bafc_1706121421_1,Data text one,Letterkenny,IE,Text data for example,)
```

> Store:

```
STORE C INTO 'output' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();

2017-06-12 14:57:19,857 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser  - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: AttemptID:attempt_1496327466789_0452_r_000000_3 Info:Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Datum 2 is not in union ["null","string"]
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:469)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:432)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:412)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Datum 2 is not in union ["null","string"]
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:308)
    at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroRecordWriter.write(PigAvroRecordWriter.java:49)
    at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage.putNext(AvroStorage.java:749)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:139)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:467)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Datum 2 is not in union ["null","string"]
    at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.resolveUnionSchema(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.writeUnion(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:111)
    at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.write(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:82)
    at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.writeRecord(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:365)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:105)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:73)
    at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.write(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:99)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:60)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:302)
    ... 19 more
```

I tried to define AVRO schema explicitly, but haven't got any success, the same error

```
STORE C INTO 'output' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage(
'schema', '{
    "name": "Myschema",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": 
    [
      {"name": "id", "type": ["string", "null"]},
      {"name": "FileName", "type": ["string", "null"]},
      {"name": "title", "type": ["string", "null"]},
      {"name": "city", "type": ["string", "null"]},
      {"name": "country", "type": ["string", "null"]},
      {"name": "text", "type": ["string", "null"]},
      {"name": "empty_text", "type": ["string", "null"]}
    ]
  }'
);
```

Type of all fields - Srting (chararray), since I've got them from XML.

> DESCRIBE C:

```
DESCRIBE C;

C: {id: chararray,CreatedTS: chararray,FileName: chararray,title: chararray,city: chararray,country: chararray,text: chararray,empty_text: chararray}
```

I couldn't find any information on the internet except this:
http://www.gauravp.com/2014/06/pig-error-error-2997-encountered.html
Pls, can someone explain ?

Answer (score 0):

Solve by implicit casting in PIG, (chararray)$0 as (id:chararray). RANK return long type - was a root cause. So always try to check types and returning types e.g from udf.